# Batch unzip .zip files using 7z

Tags: linux, command-line-interface, compression

I have downloaded a large number of .zip files and need to extract them using 7z (p7zip) at the command line. `7z x filename0001.zip` is successful, but `7z x *.zip` returns a "No files to process" error.

How can I unzip the files as a batch instead of one at a time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solution:**

`ls -1 *.zip | xargs -L 1 7z x`

**Explanation:**

1. `ls -1 *.zip` outputs a one-column list of zip files to stdout (ls dash-one, *not* ls dash-ell)
2. `xargs -L 1` takes each filename returned and passes it to `7z x` as a parameter.

Answer (score 4):

```
for zip in *.zip; do
    7z x "$zip"
done
```